# Locus of closing escalator plate hinge

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Folded plates $OA,AB,BX$ with given dimensions in inches hinging about $A,B,X$ are straightened out while closing the door in an escalator. $X$ moves on $x$ axis, fulcrum $O$ is fixed.

[image: Locus of Sliding Folded plates]

Find locus traced by $B$ (per approximate sketch).

dxiv's answer: $B$ moves on the parabola below $x$ - axis, $A$ moves on a circle inside the parabola above $x$-axis.

EDIT1:

If the joints are so flexible to allow rotation beyond $ \pi, B$ gets into opposite quadrant tracing a full ellipse!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  let $OA=r$ and $OX=4d\,$, then the coordinates of $B$ are $x=3d$ and $y=-\sqrt{r^2 - d^2}\,$. Eliminating $d$ between the two gives the equation in $x,y$ which describes the locus as ellipse

$$ (x/3)^2 + y^2 = r^2 $$

Comment: I noticed such ellipse scratch marks on some elevator car floors.Hope the edit is ok.